# How to color ParametricPlot3D based on the parameter?

Tags: plotting, color

I have a set of ODEs I am solving, and then plotting (several) trajectories of in ParametricPlot3D. I want to have a color of each plot reflect the time (i.e. the Parameter) at that point.

I tried what something along the lines of:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{Sin[t], Cos[t], t/10}, {Sin[2*t], 3*Cos[t], Tan[t]}}, {t, 0, 20},
ColorFunction -> Function[t, Hue[t]]]
```

which colors the function in a seemingly arbitrary way.

Cheers!

Comment: Look in [the details section](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html) too see what arguments are given to the `ColorFunction`. `Function[{x, y, z, t}, ...]`

Answer (score 6):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{Sin[t], Cos[t], t/10}, {Sin[2*t], 3*Cos[t], Tan[t]}}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
                 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t}, Hue[t]], 
                 PlotStyle -> Thick,
                 Exclusions -> Thread[Equal[t, Array[(2 # - 1)/2 Pi &, 2]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Please note that extending the plot till `t == 20` as you've done will cause the second function to plot along the same path several times, so occluding the "real" coloring